# What is wrong with this attempt to solve $x^x = 2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

For $x^x= 2$, hence the solution is :

$x\cdot \ln(x) = \ln(2)$

$x\cdot\int(1/x)\,dx = \ln(2)$

$\int(x/x)\,dx = \ln(2)$

$x+c = \ln(2)$, where $c = 0$

so, $x = \ln (2)$

Can someone tell me why this solution is wrong?

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title... one that deals with the content of your question.

Comment: You can not pass the factor of $x$ through the integral like that.

Comment: "$x \cdot\int(1/x)dx = \ln(2)$" $\,$ This is why you should never use an integration variable of the same name as another unrelated variable in the same expression.

Comment: To close voters: the "solution" is full of errors, but OP knows this. So what is the reason for voting to close?

Comment: Another thing that seems suspect is the assertion that the constant of integration, $c$, is $0$. The best you could conclude is that $x = \ln(2) - c$, for some constant $c$ (which, if you think about it, is actually a correct conclusion!).

Comment: Instead of writing $x\cdot\int\frac{1}{x} dx$, try writing it as $x\cdot\int\frac{1}{t} dt$. Now it should be clearer why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was in the following step
$$\int \frac{x}{x} dx$$
As you cannot transfer the $x$ into the integral that way because $x$ is not a constant. To bring it inside the integral, the new integral must evaluate to $x\ln x$. So the correct way to bring it inside will be

$$x\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\int(\ln x+1)dx$$

The actual solution requires the use of a special function called the lambert $W$ function where it has the property
$$W(xe^x)=x$$
To begin with, you need to transform your equation into the form $ue^u$, which is easy enough
$$x^x=2$$
$x=e^u$
$$e^{ue^u}=2$$
$$ue^u=\ln2$$
Using the lambert W function
$$u=W(\ln2)$$
Substituting back in for $x$
$$\ln(x)=W(\ln2)$$
$$x=e^{W(\ln2)}$$
There are many solutions for the lambert W function, however the only one with a real answer is $W(\ln 2) \approx 0.444436091$ which makes the final answer
$$x \approx 1.55961046946236$$

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the error is that you incorrectly used the linearity of integration. You couldn’t move the x inside the integral of 1/x, because x isn’t a constant, it is the variable you are integrating with respect to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community: Why is this answer not clear? It very well explains the mistake and the reason.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 community is a robot, so it automatically checks without replying.

Answer (score 2):

It should start:

$x^x = 2$

$x\cdot \ln(x) = \ln(2)$

$x\cdot\int_1^x(1/t)\,dt = \ln(2)$

And then you're stuck! Sure you can put the $x$ inside the integral, but you're integrating FROM 1 to $x$ with respect to a placeholder variable (I've used $t$). And in fact, it's basically impossible to get unstuck without "cheating". And by cheating, I mean using the Lambert W function...

The Lambert W function often shows up in solving these types of problems. We can just define $W(x)$ to be the inverse of $xe^x$, and this turns out to be something for which numerical approximations are well-known. This video explores how to solve the problem using that at a relatively accessible level: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWyMRmV1hLg .